# Why can't I access my static variables from another php page

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a simple class that holds all my session information so I can easily obtain it later on.  I don't like having to keep using $_SESSION['foo'] to access it through all my PHP pages because I want to be better organized and have all of the session data stored in one area so I can just pull up the page if I need a quick reference to see all the variables I've stored.  Also on a side note, if there is a better way I'm suppose to store SESSION data so that its organized and easily read by other programmers that would be very helpful information as well.

So far I created the following class..

```
class staticVars {

    public static $ownerID;
    public static $ownerFullName;
    public static $ownerEmail;

    public static function createFromArray($array) {
        $ownerID = $array['ownerID'];
        $ownerFullName = $array['ownerFullName'];
        $ownerEmail = $array['ownerEmail'];
    }
}
```

in my PHP page I have this...

```
include("./includes/core/coreGlobals.php");

staticVars::createFromArray($_SESSION);

 echo ("owner id " . staticVars::$ownerID);
```

However, when I echo out the response, the $ownerID just comes back blank.

Comment: You probably ment to do `$this->ownerID = $array['ownerID'];`, as you want to assign to the class-variable, not the local variable inside that function.

Comment: You can't do $this to a non-object.  Self was the route to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting variables local to the function and not the class variables.  Use `self` or maybe `static`:

```
public static function createFromArray($array) {
    self::$ownerID = $array['ownerID'];
    self::$ownerFullName = $array['ownerFullName'];
    self::$ownerEmail = $array['ownerEmail'];
}
```

See: [Late Static Bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) for when you would use `static`.